# I want to animate the movement of a foreign OS X app's window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, accessibility

Background: I recently got two monitors and want a way to move the focused window to the other screen and vice versa. I've achieved this by using the Accessibility API. (Specifically, I get an AXUIElementRef that holds the AXUIElement associated with the focused window, then I set the NSAccessibilityPositionAttribute value to move the window.

I have this working almost exactly the way I want it to, except I want to animate the movement of windows. I thought that if I could get the NSWindow somehow, I could get its layer and use CoreAnimation to animate the window movement.

Unfortunately, I found out that this isn't possible. (Correct me I'm wrong though -- if there's a way to do it this way it'd be great!) So I'm asking you all for help. How should I go about animating the movement of the focused window, if I have access to the AXUIElementRef?

-R

--**EDIT**

I was able to get a crude animation going by creating a while loop and moving the position of the window by a small amount each time to make a successful animation. However, the results are pretty sub-par. As you can guess, it takes a lot of unnecessary processing power, and is still very choppy. There *must* be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible way I can imagine would be to perform some hacky property comparison between the AXUIElement info values for the window and the info returned from the CGWindow api.  Once you're able to ascertain what windows in the CGWindow API match AXUIElementRefs, you could grab bitmaps of the current window contents, overlay the screen with your own custom animation draw of the faux windows, then as you drop the overlay set the real AXUIElementRef's to the desired-end-animation positions.

Hacky, tho.

Comment: This is the best I've been able to come up with as well. I'm going to try this and see if there's any appreciable performance gain in comparison to just moving the position of the window bit by bit iteratively.